# Error querying database using Diesel, r2d2, and r2d2-diesel

Tags: mysql, rust, rust-diesel

I've set up a system using a connection pooling system utilizing [diesel](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel), [r2d2](https://github.com/sfackler/r2d2), and [r2d2-diesel](https://github.com/diesel-rs/r2d2-diesel) to serve as an API host for my web application.  I've been following this [blog post](https://mgattozzi.com/diesel-powered-rocket) as a basis which has helped me set things up.  However, I've made a modification of switching to MySQL for my database backend; I've added the necessary diesel features and assumed it wouldn't be an issue.

Here's the code I use to set up a connection pool (very much the same as from the blog post):

```
use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::mysql::MysqlConnection;
use r2d2::{ GetTimeout, Pool, PooledConnection, Config };
use r2d2_diesel::ConnectionManager;

pub struct DB(PooledConnection<ConnectionManager<MysqlConnection>>);

impl DB {
    pub fn conn(&self) -> &MysqlConnection {
        &*self.0
    }
}

pub fn create_db_pool() -> Pool<ConnectionManager<MysqlConnection>> {
    let config = Config::default();
    let manager = ConnectionManager::<MysqlConnection>::new(format!("{}", DB_CREDENTIALS));
    Pool::new(config, manager).expect("Failed to create pool.")
}
```

I've been encountering an issue during the process of setting up the database interface system.  When I make any query to the database through diesel, I get the following error: `Err(DatabaseError(__Unknown, "Commands out of sync; you can\'t run this command now"))`

I've done some research and it seems that this error occurs when a previous query hasn't been read before sending another, leading me to believe that this may be a library error.  I checked the MySQL query log, and I see no queries at all other than those for creating the connections in the connection pools.

I've reduced my error down to a test case.  The following responds with the error message I pasted above:

```
/// Make sure we can run basic queries on the database using a connection pool
#[test]
fn basic_queries() {
    use diesel::connection::SimpleConnection;

    let mut pool = create_db_pool();
    let mut conn = pool.get().unwrap();
    let res = conn.batch_execute("SELECT 1");
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

The same error message was produced by running a query like the following, but that's much more difficult to reduce to a single test case:

```
let query = diesel::insert(&beatmap).into(schema::beatmaps::dsl::beatmaps);
// println!("{:?}", query);
print_sql!(query);
let conn: &MysqlConnection = &*client.pool.get().expect("Unable to get connection from pool");
let res = query.execute(conn);
```

I'd like to think that this is an implementation error on my part, but is it possible this has something to do with my database configuration?  The database I'm using for development is in active use by over 3 languages and several applications without issue, so I doubt it.

Comment: It does seem to indeed be an issue with the Diesel library and r2d2-diesel: https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/728

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT: This has been fixed in the latest versions of the involved crates.**

It turns out that the `r2d2-diesel` library [is currently broken for MySQL](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/728).  The health check makes a query but never reads the result out which messes up the MySQL command ordering for user-made queries.

I made a fork of the `r2d2-diesel` repository that fixes the issue.  It is not designed as a long-term solution and **only works for MySQL clients**.  If you'd like to use it, add the following to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
r2d2-diesel-mysql = { git = "https://github.com/Ameobea/r2d2-diesel" }
```

Change all instances of `r2d2_diesel` to `r2d2_diesel_mysql` in your codebase and it should work as a drop-in replacement.

Comment: A fix to this has been released.